# Document Viewer in popup angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I want to show all kinds of document like doc,pdf,excel and also images like png or jpeg in popup using Angular js.

I found one solution in java script http://www.aspsnippets.com/demos/1261/ which does same but it not supports excel and doc files.

Is there any relevant way for angular js to do same for all kind images and files?

Comment: If I understood you correctly you want to implement reading functionality of google spreadsheet or docs?

Comment: yes exactly i want like how attached file we can open in gmail

Comment: unfortunately this is bigger than I am capable of doing. try to look at those things http://www.angularjs4u.com/modules/5-angularjs-microsoft-word-excel-integrations/ Maybe something will help you in doing your stuff

Comment: i think you understand different
i want to preview the file which is already in my server. just like gmail it has already uploaded file it just open it. i want to do it. not to create file format

Comment: I know. And I said it is quite big task, and I do not know how to do it. I am aware that those examples are not what you need - but they can give you an idea maybe.